# list instead of separated arguments in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use function  `np.random.curve_fit(x,a,b,c,...,z)` with a big but fixed number of fitting parameters. Is it possible to use tuples or lists here for shortness, like `np.random.curve_fit(x,P)`, where `P=(a,b,c,...,z)`?

Comment: use `*` : `np.random.normal(x,*P)`

Comment: And none of them takes an *args list... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to convert your example, you would use  `np.random.normal(x, *P)`. However, `np.random.normal(x,a,b,c,...,z)` wouldn't actually work. Maybe you meant another function?

Comment: For this case, should I use P=(a,b,c) or P=[a,b,c]? Or, maybe, it does not matter?

Comment: @freude: Doens't matter, any iterable should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
np.random.normal(x, *P)
```

The asterisk says "take the remaining arguments from this sequence."

See [4.7.4. Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: For this case, should I use P=(a,b,c) or P=[a,b,c]? Or, maybe, it does not matter?

Comment: @freude: It doesn't matter - lists and tuples are both sequences, and will be treated the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the unpacking operator:

```
np.random.normal(x, *P)
```